# last iteration of loop not fetching count from select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table from which i am selecting data and then checking the fetched data from another table if it exist then will do something else null;

```
create table cmts_data (cmts_token varchar2(30), IP varchar2(20));



insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-01-1','10.15.0.1');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-02-2','10.15.0.2');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-03-3','10.15.0.3');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-04-4','10.15.0.4');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-05-5','10.15.0.5');
```

another table from where i select data--

```
create table link_data (dhcp_token varchar2(30), cmts_to_add     varchar2(200), cmts_to_remove varchar2(200));



insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-1','wnlb-cmts-01-1,wnlb-cmts-02-2', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-2','wnlb-cmts-03-3,wnlb-cmts-04-4,wnlb-cmts-05-5', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-3','wnlb-cmts-01-1', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-4','wnlb-cmts-05-8,wnlb-cmts-05-6,wnlb-cmts-05-0,wnlb-cmts-03-3', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-5','wnlb-cmts-02-2,wnlb-cmts-04-4,wnlb-cmts-05-7', null);

create table subntwk (subntwk_nm varchar2(30));



insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-1');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-2');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-3');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-4');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-5');
```

These are structure and sample data for the two tables

Now i have this PLSQL block --

```
DECLARE

  l_cmts VARCHAR2( 200 CHAR );

  l_cmts_1 VARCHAR2( 200 CHAR );

  l_dhcp_cnt number;

  l_cmts_cnt number;



BEGIN

  FOR r IN ( SELECT dhcp_token, cmts_to_add || ',' cmts

              FROM link_data

          )

  LOOP

    l_cmts := r.cmts;

    l_cmts_1 := trim(SUBSTR( l_cmts, 1, INSTR(l_cmts, ',' ) - 1 ));

    dbms_output.put_line(r.dhcp_token);

      select count(1) into l_dhcp_cnt from subntwk where subntwk_nm = r.dhcp_token;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_dhcp_cnt );

  --  WHILE l_cmts_1 IS NOT NULL

    LOOP

      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r.dhcp_token || '|' || l_cmts_1 );



      dbms_output.put_line(l_cmts_1);

      select count(1) into l_cmts_cnt from cmts_data where trim(cmts_token) = trim(l_cmts_1);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cmts_cnt);



/*     

      if l_dhcp_cnt >0 and l_cmts_cnt > 0 then

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r.dhcp_token || '|' || l_cmts_1 );

      end if;

*/   

      l_cmts := trim(SUBSTR( l_cmts, INSTR( l_cmts, ',' ) + 1 ));

      l_cmts_1 := trim(SUBSTR( l_cmts, 1, INSTR( l_cmts, ',' ) - 1 ));



    exit when l_cmts_1 is null;

    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

And DBMS_OUTPUT of this block is ---

```
dhcp-1-1-1

1

wnlb-cmts-01-1

1

wnlb-cmts-02-2

0

dhcp-1-1-2

1

wnlb-cmts-03-3

1

wnlb-cmts-04-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-5

0

dhcp-1-1-3

1

wnlb-cmts-01-1

0

dhcp-1-1-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-8

0

wnlb-cmts-05-6

0

wnlb-cmts-05-0

0

wnlb-cmts-03-3

0

dhcp-1-1-5

1

wnlb-cmts-02-2

1

wnlb-cmts-04-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-7

0
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT --

```
dhcp-1-1-1

1

wnlb-cmts-01-1

1

wnlb-cmts-02-2

1

dhcp-1-1-2

1

wnlb-cmts-03-3

1

wnlb-cmts-04-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-5

1

dhcp-1-1-3

1

wnlb-cmts-01-1

1

dhcp-1-1-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-8

0

wnlb-cmts-05-6

0

wnlb-cmts-05-0

0

wnlb-cmts-03-3

1

dhcp-1-1-5

1

wnlb-cmts-02-2

1

wnlb-cmts-04-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-7

0
```

Here as we can see that in each last iteration of the inner loop it gives me the l_cmts_1 name as it is but why the count of that last l_cmts_1 is 0.

here i put some non-existing values also as it can be in my scenario for that i am getting 0 that is fine but the behaiour of this PLSQL block as i see is that for inner loop it gives the name of variable but the select statement (for count) is not taking it !!

i have tried to put that select statement at different place in the block but none is working.

SQL that i tried ---

```
with link_data_expand  
    as  
   (  
     select dhcp_token  
          , regexp_substr(cmts_to_add, '[^,]+', 1, level) cmts_to_add  
       from link_data  
    connect  
         by level <= length(cmts_to_add) - length(replace(cmts_to_add, ',')) + 1  
  and prior dhcp_token = dhcp_token  
   and prior dbms_random.value() is not null  
   )  
   select a.dhcp_token  
        , a.cmts_to_add  
        , count(b.cmts_token) cnt  
     from link_data_expand a  
     left join  
          cmts_data b  
       on a.cmts_to_add = b.cmts_token  
    group  
       by a.dhcp_token  
        , a.cmts_to_add  
     order  
      by a.dhcp_token  
        , a.cmts_to_add;
```

result of SQL --

```
 DHCP_TOKEN    CMTS_TO_ADD    CNT

 dhcp-1-1-1    wnlb-cmts-01-1    1

 dhcp-1-1-1    wnlb-cmts-02-2  0

 dhcp-1-1-2    wnlb-cmts-03-3    1

 dhcp-1-1-2    wnlb-cmts-04-4    1

 dhcp-1-1-2    wnlb-cmts-05-5  0

 dhcp-1-1-3    wnlb-cmts-01-1  0

 dhcp-1-1-4    wnlb-cmts-03-3  0

 dhcp-1-1-4    wnlb-cmts-05-0    0

 dhcp-1-1-4    wnlb-cmts-05-6    0

 dhcp-1-1-4    wnlb-cmts-05-8    0

 dhcp-1-1-5    wnlb-cmts-02-2    1

 dhcp-1-1-5    wnlb-cmts-04-4    1

 dhcp-1-1-5    wnlb-cmts-05-7    0
```

Any suggestion what i have done wrong here !

DB version -

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Isn't a count of 0 correct for "wnlb-cmts-05-7"? That value doesn't appear in the cmts_data table. Also, is there a reason why you're doing this in a pl/sql procedure, rather than a select statement?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Boneist--Ok, I have this scenario i'll be provided with .csv file to load data into DB.

I am using SQL LOADER to load data from .csv to staging table which is link_data.

now in link_data second and third column have fields with comma to separate these fields from comma i use substr() and instr() functions.

NOW after fetching all these fields from LINK_DATA i need to check first that if these extracted values from link_data is already present in The subntwk and cmts_data table if yes then insert these fields in the another DB table else do nothing.

Comment: @Boneist--Here one DHCP can have multiple CMTS associated with them

so i suppose if
dhcp-1-1-1 wnlb-cmts-01-1


both are present in the subntwk and cmts_data table then i can insert it into another table if one of them is not present then i can not insert into another table.

I hope this clarify my requirement.

i know its a easy one but the problem is last iteration of CMTS loop is giving me zero count which results in the failure of my furhter login to insert data into another table.

Comment: @Boneist--So it is my requirement.and the result for "wnlb-cmts-05-7" is correct as there could be some CMTS which may be not present in the DB so i have avoid that and proceed further as the data is coming in CSV file

Comment: the last iteration is giving you 0 count because there is no data in the table for the last value (wnlb-cmts-05-7). I fail to see why this is an issue?

Comment: @ammoQ--dhcp-1-1-1

1

wnlb-cmts-01-1

1

wnlb-cmts-02-2

1

dhcp-1-1-2

1

wnlb-cmts-03-3

1

wnlb-cmts-04-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-5

1

dhcp-1-1-3

1

wnlb-cmts-01-1

1

dhcp-1-1-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-8

0

wnlb-cmts-05-6

0

wnlb-cmts-05-0

0

wnlb-cmts-03-3

1

dhcp-1-1-5

1

wnlb-cmts-02-2

1

wnlb-cmts-04-4

1

wnlb-cmts-05-7

0

Comment: @Boneist--no i think you are getting me wrong or have not ckeck the result i need. Actually suppose for 'wnlb-cmts-02-2' it is giving me count as 0 but it is there in cmts_data table because my requirement is like that for 'dhcp-1-1-1' in subntwk table there are two cmts in cmts_data which are 'wnlb-cmts-01-1' and 'wnlb-cmts-02-2' so for that i have to check if that DHCP is present in the subntwk table and both these CMTS are present in the CMTS_DATA table if yes then insert it into LINK table as  'dhcp-1-1-1'_TO_ wnlb-cmts-01-1' and 'dhcp-1-1-1'_TO_ wnlb-cmts-02-2' these are two rows in LINK.

Comment: This will be true for all other DHCP' and CMTS's. i have that SQL also but it again gives me same result.i"ll post it in my question please check there

Comment: I think I see what you mean - it's the "last" iteration for each dhcp token. Anyway, when I ran the procedure, it gave me the correct results as per your expected output.

Comment: @Boneist--Then why it not giving me in my SQL developer, TOAD , SQL PLUS i did nothing wrong.any reason please i am just not getting it why this is happening with me although its not that much a big problem but this 0 count is making it impossible for me. i have tried trim(). what is happening  :(

Comment: I've updated my answer below with the output I got from running your procedure. I've done nothing different from what you've put in your question, apart from add a missing commit after your insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've put in the comments above, I believe the following query should give you what you need:

```
with link_info as (select dhcp_token,
                          cmts_to_add,
                          cmts_to_remove,
                          trim(regexp_substr(cmts_to_add, '[^,]+', 1, level)) sub_cmt_to_add
                   from   link_data
                   connect by prior dhcp_token = dhcp_token
                              and prior dbms_random.value is not null
                              and level <= regexp_count(cmts_to_add, ',') + 1)

select li.dhcp_token,
       sn.subntwk_nm,
       li.sub_cmt_to_add,
       trim(cd.cmts_token) cmts_token,
       cd.ip
from   link_info li
       left outer join cmts_data cd on (li.sub_cmt_to_add = trim(cd.cmts_token))
       left outer join subntwk sn on (li.dhcp_token = sn.subntwk_nm);

DHCP_TOKEN SUBNTWK_NM SUB_CMT_TO_ADD  CMTS_TOKEN      IP        
---------- ---------- --------------- --------------- ----------
dhcp-1-1-1 dhcp-1-1-1 wnlb-cmts-02-2  wnlb-cmts-02-2  10.15.0.2 
dhcp-1-1-1 dhcp-1-1-1 wnlb-cmts-01-1  wnlb-cmts-01-1  10.15.0.1 
dhcp-1-1-2 dhcp-1-1-2 wnlb-cmts-05-5  wnlb-cmts-05-5  10.15.0.5 
dhcp-1-1-2 dhcp-1-1-2 wnlb-cmts-04-4  wnlb-cmts-04-4  10.15.0.4 
dhcp-1-1-2 dhcp-1-1-2 wnlb-cmts-03-3  wnlb-cmts-03-3  10.15.0.3 
dhcp-1-1-3 dhcp-1-1-3 wnlb-cmts-01-1  wnlb-cmts-01-1  10.15.0.1 
dhcp-1-1-4 dhcp-1-1-4 wnlb-cmts-05-0                            
dhcp-1-1-4 dhcp-1-1-4 wnlb-cmts-05-6                            
dhcp-1-1-4 dhcp-1-1-4 wnlb-cmts-05-8                            
dhcp-1-1-4 dhcp-1-1-4 wnlb-cmts-03-3  wnlb-cmts-03-3  10.15.0.3 
dhcp-1-1-5 dhcp-1-1-5 wnlb-cmts-05-7                            
dhcp-1-1-5 dhcp-1-1-5 wnlb-cmts-04-4  wnlb-cmts-04-4  10.15.0.4 
dhcp-1-1-5 dhcp-1-1-5 wnlb-cmts-02-2  wnlb-cmts-02-2  10.15.0.2
```

The advantage of having the data in a sql statement is that you can then plug that into an INSERT/MERGE/UPDATE statement as appropriate to do the necessary amendments.

---

Regarding your issue, I have no idea why you're seeing 0 counts for the last iteration of each dhcp_token. I ran your exact create table / insert statements / anonymous block and got the expected results (I did add a commit at the end of the insert statements, though).

This is what I ran as a script (in Toad):

```
drop table cmts_data;
drop table link_data;
drop table subntwk;

create table cmts_data (cmts_token varchar2(30), IP varchar2(20));

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-01-1','10.15.0.1');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-02-2','10.15.0.2');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-03-3','10.15.0.3');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-04-4','10.15.0.4');

insert into cmts_data values ('wnlb-cmts-05-5','10.15.0.5');

create table link_data (dhcp_token varchar2(30), cmts_to_add     varchar2(200), cmts_to_remove varchar2(200));



insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-1','wnlb-cmts-01-1,wnlb-cmts-02-2', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-2','wnlb-cmts-03-3,wnlb-cmts-04-4,wnlb-cmts-05-5', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-3','wnlb-cmts-01-1', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-4','wnlb-cmts-05-8,wnlb-cmts-05-6,wnlb-cmts-05-0,wnlb-cmts-03-3', null);

insert into link_data values ('dhcp-1-1-5','wnlb-cmts-02-2,wnlb-cmts-04-4,wnlb-cmts-05-7', null);

create table subntwk (subntwk_nm varchar2(30));



insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-1');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-2');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-3');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-4');

insert into subntwk values ('dhcp-1-1-5');

commit;

set serveroutput on;

DECLARE

  l_cmts VARCHAR2( 200 CHAR );

  l_cmts_1 VARCHAR2( 200 CHAR );

  l_dhcp_cnt number;

  l_cmts_cnt number;



BEGIN

  FOR r IN ( SELECT dhcp_token, cmts_to_add || ',' cmts

              FROM link_data

          )

  LOOP

    l_cmts := r.cmts;

    l_cmts_1 := trim(SUBSTR( l_cmts, 1, INSTR(l_cmts, ',' ) - 1 ));

    dbms_output.put_line(r.dhcp_token);

      select count(1) into l_dhcp_cnt from subntwk where subntwk_nm = r.dhcp_token;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_dhcp_cnt );

  --  WHILE l_cmts_1 IS NOT NULL

    LOOP

      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r.dhcp_token || '|' || l_cmts_1 );



      dbms_output.put_line(l_cmts_1);

      select count(1) into l_cmts_cnt from cmts_data where trim(cmts_token) = trim(l_cmts_1);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cmts_cnt);



/*     

      if l_dhcp_cnt >0 and l_cmts_cnt > 0 then

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r.dhcp_token || '|' || l_cmts_1 );

      end if;

*/   

      l_cmts := trim(SUBSTR( l_cmts, INSTR( l_cmts, ',' ) + 1 ));

      l_cmts_1 := trim(SUBSTR( l_cmts, 1, INSTR( l_cmts, ',' ) - 1 ));



    exit when l_cmts_1 is null;

    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;

END;
/
```

And this is the output I got:

```
Table dropped.
Table dropped.
Table dropped.
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
Commit complete.
dhcp-1-1-1
1
wnlb-cmts-01-1
1
wnlb-cmts-02-2
1
dhcp-1-1-2
1
wnlb-cmts-03-3
1
wnlb-cmts-04-4
1
wnlb-cmts-05-5
1
dhcp-1-1-3
1
wnlb-cmts-01-1
1
dhcp-1-1-4
1
wnlb-cmts-05-8
0
wnlb-cmts-05-6
0
wnlb-cmts-05-0
0
wnlb-cmts-03-3
1
dhcp-1-1-5
1
wnlb-cmts-02-2
1
wnlb-cmts-04-4
1
wnlb-cmts-05-7
0
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Yes thats what i want why it is not giving me this result !!please give me this in my TOAD i have to deleiver it by tomorrow i because of this unknow problem i am not able to test it. So how will i deliver it.i think its problem with my tools !!

Comment: I've given you exactly what I ran in my Toad. I can't give you anything else! Perhaps you could try copying and running the exact script I pasted in my answer and see what that results in? I would highly recommend you switch to using the sql statement (or something similar if that doesn't quite match with what you're after).

Comment: i know that i have the SQL ready also but as you can see that the SQL is also giving me the same result then whats the point i can use any of these two methods but only if at least one or both of them give me correct result to test or should i assume it as in production environment it will run correctly and proceed with further validation and write insert statement in that BLOCK but that LINK has dependencies  on subntwk table thats why i am not able to test it

Comment: are you saying that when you run the sql statement, it doesn't give the same result as the one I posted in my answer? If so, I can only assume that the data in your tables is not the same as the data in my tables, meaning we did not run the same insert statements. I ran exactly what you posted, though, so...

Comment: I did commit also and i doing it with SQL LOADER and running SQL SCRIPTS in a SHELL SCRIPTS which are auto commit.

Comment: did you try running the same script as I did? (ie. drop the tables, re-create, insert, run procedure)

Comment: No it can not because i give you data from the .CSV file which i have created for testing purpose. This all data, staging table .csv files are created by me there is nothing wrong in it. whereas when i run this SQL SELECT count(1) FROM CMTS_DATA WHERE CMTS_TOKEM = 'wnlb-cmts-02-2'; then it gives me count as 1 but when tried it using that PLSQL or that SQL then it gives me 0 :(

Comment: ok got it now i get same result as your but what will be the problem with my data i have created it by typing all the .csv files i need to check again its going to be a headache now for me.Now i'll take it real data will be good and mine is bad and will put commit in my SQL scripts in which i loading data from staging tables to main table for DHCP and CMTS then will see if its works

Comment: what do you get when you run `select * from link_data where cmts_to_add like '%wnlb-cmts-02-2%';`? I get 2 rows (one for dhcp-1-1-1 and one for dhcp-1-1-5). I suspect you'll get 0 or 1 row returned, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Boneist its good that you put your efforts and it really help me ease when you posted the correct result :)